# Адаптивный текст

Tags: css

Можно ли на сегодняшний день добиться адаптивности для текста не используя кучу '@media' запросов?

Comment: с какой версии `ie` требуется поддержка?

Comment: С 10, но можно обойтись и без поддержки в ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `font-size` можно использовать несколько вариантов:

**1.** Использовать единицу измерения `vw`.
`vw` = 1 % от ширины пользовательской части окна браузера.

```
p {
  font-size: 10vw; // 10% от viewport
}
```

[Поддержка браузеров vw](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw)

**2.** Использовать `calc` и `vw`

```
p {
  font-size: (calc(14px + 2 * ((100vw - 420px) / 860)))
}
```

[Поддержка браузеров calc](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Так или иначе нужно будет подбирать нужные размеры.

Так же, можно посмотреть небольшую библиотеку [Rucksack](http://simplaio.github.io/rucksack/docs/#responsive-type), тут как раз используется `vw` и `calc`

Comment: А можно ли сделать зависимость от ширины контейнера, а не всего окна просмотра?

Comment: @ИванСмирнов ниже я предложил сделать песочницу, но думаю что решением будет либо через `js`, либо через `@media`.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь единицей измерения `vw`

> 1vw = 1% от viewport width

Пример

```
h1 {
    font-size: 5.7vw;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 4.0vw;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 2.8vw;
}
p {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
}
```

Демо
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewportTypography/

Comment: А кроме этого есть ли еще альтернатива?
изменять текст в зависимости от ширины  div к сожелению не получается, макет не позволяет сделать аккуратно

Comment: Вам от чего нужно менять?

Comment: Просто тест должен быть расположен над изображением, и смещаться максимум пикселей на 10, а изображение пришлось задовать тегом img так как нужно наложить тень, было бы через background так там понятно, строю все на сетке bootstrap 3

Comment: @ИванСмирнов будет лучше, если сделаете песочницу и опишите условия.